# Google admob errod on return ad

Tags: android

I keep getting this error in my debug when ads are about to be displayed.

```
07-16 14:35:29.630: INFO/Ads(12137): onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad request successful, but no ad returned due to lack of ad inventory.)
```

What does this mean and how do i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't fix that - just there is no ads in adMob, so you haven't got one.

Comment: Put some home add - it should appear more frequent. I'don't know if there is still some test mode - adMob API has changed a lot last time.

Answer (score 0):

This essentially means Admob does not have enough ad to fill. This is not an error and you can 
leave it as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are correct, there are no ads to fill. However, you can [link your AdMob to your AdSense account](http://helpcenter.admob.com/content/enabling-google-adsense-ads-your-applications), which will allow it to fill from there as well.